# git: fatal exceeded maximum include depth

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I came across [MinGit](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.32.0.windows.1) when I wanted to avoid the extra stuff that Git for Windows included in the insallation (Git BASH, Git GUI, etc..). It's supposed to be a minimal installation of Git with only the CLI tool.

Unfortunately, after installing it and adding the `cmd` folder that housed `git.exe` to PATH, things didn't work as expected.

On Command Prompt, any command using `git` would be followed by this error message.[image: git error]

I've looked around online and I can't find any explanation or fix for this. It looks to be related to the `gitconfig` file, but I don't know what to do with it to fix this message.

Edit: Here is what is in the gitconfig file[image]

Comment: What's in that `gitconfig` file?

Comment: Just as the error message suggested: you include the file in itself (last line)

Comment: Thank you @JanWilamowski, that fixed it. I feel dumb for not noticing that. You may want to put that down as an answer and I would gladly mark it accepted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make clear - The right answer was posted as a comment by @jan-wilamowski

- In your `gitconfig` you have added the last line which tries to include the file itself.
- the result is an "endless" loop, you `gitconfig` try to load `gitconfig` which try to load `gitconfig` and so on.

#### Solution

The solution is to remove the last line which will result in "breaking" the endless recursion which caused the original problem.